# How can I fetch current or latest version number of a list item using PowerShell scripting

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, document-library, splistitem, versioning

I want to fetch latest or current version of an item in a document library.

How can I achieve this using PowerShell Scripting?

Is `$version.VersionLabel` value of version number?

But I don't want to loop through `$item.Versions`, I just want the current or latest version of an item.

Thanks in advance.`

```
foreach($item in $ItemCollection)
{
    foreach($version in $item.Versions)
    {
    Write-Host "Documen Library:" $list.Title "-" "Document:" $item.Title $version.VersionLabel
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that you want to get all the latest version items in a document library??

Answer (score 2):

The latest version can be found at first index of `$item.Versions`. Try following

```
foreach($item in $ItemCollection)
  {
      Write-Host "Documen Library:" $list.Title "-" "Document:" $item.Title $item.Versions[0].VersionLabel
  }
```

## Current/Latest Version

```
$item.Versions[0].VersionLabel
```